# What times are considered to be 夜中?

Tags: words

I know that yonaka is considered to be during the middle of the night. Are specific time periods involved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/228064/meaning/m0u/) defines `夜中` as, among other things, `夜のなかば` - literally "middle of the night". Much as in English, there is no firm definition of exactly when the "middle of the night" is. Ultimately a person's interpretation is going to depend to some degree on their lifestyle, opinions, and many other things.

That said, according to an investigation the NHK did a while ago, it seems like many people think of `夜中` as starting at 11 PM and ending at 3 AM.

Note: see [here](https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/research/001.html) for the investigation original text. It literally says `午後11時台～午前2時台`, but my assumption is that `午前2時台` encompasses the period of time between 2 and 3 AM and consequently the entire period of time ends at 3.